# How to Find and Replace date format in Excel Comments using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2016

I have Cells with Comments such as the following:

> May 26, 2017: Reduced from 1000 to 900

I want to use VBA to Find and Replace only the date format within the comments from:

> MMM DD, YYYY

to

> YYYY/MM/DD

The best code I could find after searching for several hours is the following but unfortunately, it does only Find and Replace text with a text. I tried to make it work with formats but I couldn't.

```
Sub ReplaceComments()
Dim cmt As Comment
Dim wks As Worksheet
Dim sFind As String
Dim sReplace As String
Dim sCmt As String
sFind = "2011"
sReplace = "2012"
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
For Each cmt In wks.Comments
sCmt = cmt.Text
If InStr(sCmt, sFind) <> 0 Then
sCmt = Application.WorksheetFunction. _
Substitute(sCmt, sFind, sReplace)
cmt.Text Text:=sCmt
End If
Next
Next
Set wks = Nothing
Set cmt = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Is the comment always in the format of Date: Description?

Comment: Unfortunately, as stated/shown in my question the comment contains more text beside the date. Not only date.

Comment: Consider this: extract the left end of the string up to `:`.  Attempt to convert it to a date with DateSerial. If it converts format the resulting date as MMM DD, YYYY and compare to the original extracted string. If they match format the date as YYYY/MM/DD and replace strings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try this code below.

Make sure you make a copy of your work before using it.
As @Kevin says, success will depend on the format variation used during data entry.
The code you provided is going through all sheets in your workbook, is it what you want ?

Still, make a try and come back if not suitable.

```
Sub test_comment()

Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Dim Cmt As Comment

For Each Wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Cmt In Wsh.Comments
        If InStr(1, Cmt.Text, ":") > 0 Then
            St1 = Cmt.Text
            St2 = Format(Left(St1, InStr(1, St1, ":") - 1), "YYYY/MM/DD")
            Cmt.Text St2 & Mid(St1, InStr(1, St1, ":"))
        End If
    Next Cmt
Next Wsh

End Sub
```

New try for multiple lines :

```
Sub test_comment()

Dim Wsh As Worksheet
Dim Cmt As Comment

For Each Wsh In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    For Each Cmt In Wsh.Comments
        Arr1 = Split(Cmt.Text, Chr(10))
        For i = 0 To UBound(Arr1)
            If InStr(1, Arr1(i), ":") > 0 Then
                St1 = Arr1(i)
                St2 = Format(Left(St1, InStr(1, St1, ":") - 1), "YYYY/MM/DD")
                Arr1(i) = St2 & Mid(St1, InStr(1, St1, ":"))
                Cmt.Text Join(Arr1, Chr(10))
            End If
        Next i
    Next Cmt
Next Wsh

End Sub
```

Comment: Awesome. It did work but I noticed something. If there are several lines in the comments with Date, it will work on the first line only. As shown in the following comment:

2014/08/20: Reduced from $3,499 to $2,499
Mar 27, 2015: Reduced from $2,499 to $1,999

Comment: Good code, I would add two checks 1) Validate it is a date 2) only reformat if needed

Comment: Wow! Awesome. It works exactly the way I want it. Thank you so much!